# Cocos2d blur with shaders

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, shader, blur

Currently I am toying with Cocos2D. I want to be able to blur the entire scene when there is a notification overlay displaying.

I thought I could do this with shaders (I am quite an OpenGL noob). From what I found is that there are "fsh" files which contain an algoritm for the shader. I found one for "[gausian blurring](https://github.com/aninggo/cocos2d-x-for-cocoa-port/blob/master/HelloLua/Resource/Shaders/Blur.fsh)" but how can I add such a shader to an CCScene of Cocos2D?

I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just started to play a little bit with shaders myself. There's a lot of material on the web to read and try out. I'll point you in the direction of some urls I found useful to get to understand how/what they do.. that might get you started.

**Simple tutorial to achieve a greyscale effect with shaders (Cocos2D)**

http://www.shaderdev.com/2013/09/16/full-scene-shader-effects-how-to-create-a-grayscale-pause-screen-using-ccrendertexture/

**Coding experiments blogpost: great looking shader effect. This is the shader I share for cocos2D below...**

http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2010/06/frosted-glass.html

With those you are surely on your way. Feel free to use the shaders below too if you find them useful, these were taken from the second url.

**vertex shader**

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attirbute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;
varying lowp vec2 v_fragmentColor;
varying lowp vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
    v_fragmentColor = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

**fragment shader**

```
varying lowp vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying lowp vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

float rand(vec2 co)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(92.,80.))) +
                 cos(dot(co.xy ,vec2(41.,62.))) * 5.1);
}

void main()
{
    vec2 rnd = vec2(0.0);
    rnd = vec2(rand(v_texCoord),rand(v_texCoord));
    glFragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord+rnd*0.05);
}
```